# Why i cant get any notifications email of my own repo

Tags: github

If my own repo have issue or PR, I cannot get any notifications.
Any idea why?

I have set GitHub notifications, web and email.
I can receive notifications from the issue or PR which I create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, you should be `Watching` (be notified of all conversations) on your public/private repositories. But, if that's not happening, it's that you had unwatched these repositories at some stage. It can be changed to watch again though.

That should be covered by the ["Watch" feature](https://help.github.com/en/articles/watching-and-unwatching-repositories):

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/repository/repo-actions-watch.png]

Here is how you can watch your own repository.

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/notifications/watch-repository.png]